# Semisimple Rings are Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

I have seen the statement that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $R$ is a semisimple ring, then $R$ is Noetherian several times while reading through some algebra resources; however, I have never seen an explanation for it. The definition of a semisimple ring that I know is a ring that is the direct sum of minimal ideals. This definition alone doesn't imply that $R$ is Noetherian. Is there another way I should be thinking about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- Every minimal ideal is a Noetherian $R$-module (why?).
- You can write $R$ as a finite direct sum of minimal ideals (why?).
- A finite direct sum of Noetherian modules is Noetherian.

Comment: Well every minimal ideal is simple as an $R$-module, meaning it is noetherian since it has only two submodules correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok so then for your second point, why can $R$ be written as a finite direct sum of minimal ideals?

Comment: Suppose $R=\oplus_j I_j$. You can write $1=r_1+\cdots+ r_n$, where $r_i\in I_i$. Then $R=\oplus_{j=1}^n I_j$.

Comment: Then of course a finite direct sum of Noetherian modules is noetherian.

Answer (score 5):

You'd like to prove that every right ideal is finitely generated, but even more is true:

> Every right ideal of a semisimple ring is **principal**!

Of course, you already know every right ideal is a summand, and a summand of $R_R$ is generated by an idempotent.

Comment: Very interesting! I had a quick question. Can anything be said about a commutative division ring with identity, i.e. a field. In other words, are fields necessarily semisimple?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen Of course, yes.

Comment: what's the rational there?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen the rationale is that a field is, as a module, a direct sum of one single simple submodule.